# Scheduled Task for PowerShell Script with String Array Parameter

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameters, scheduled-tasks

I've created a PowerShell script that runs perfectly from the Management Shell. I'm trying to get it setup to work in a scheduled task in Windows Server 2008 R2 and am unsure how to pass the parameters for my string array parameter.

Here is the relevant portion of my script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
        $BaseDirectory,
    [String]
        $BackupMethod = "Full",
    [Int]
        $RemoveOlderThanDays = 0,
    [String]
        $LogDirectory,
    [Int]
        $LogKeepDays = 7,
    [String[]]
        $AdditionalDirectories
)

if ($AdditionalDirectories -and $AdditionalDirectories.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "  Additional Directories to be included:" -ForegroundColor Green
    $AdditionalDirectories | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "     $_" -foregroundcolor green
    }
}
```

The parameter giving the trouble is that last one, `$AdditionalDirectories`.

### **From the Shell:**

If I run the script from the Management Shell like this, it works perfectly:

```
.\FarmBackup.ps1 \\SomeServer\Backups Full 0 D:\Logs\Backups 0 "D:\Documents\PowerShell Scripts","D:\SomeFolder"
```

**Result:**

```
   Additional Directories to be included:
      D:/Documents/PowerShell Scripts
      D:/SomeFolder
```

### **From Scheduled Task:**

**Action:** *Start a program*

**Program/script:** *PowerShell.exe*

**Arguments:** *-File "D:\Documents\PowerShell Scripts\FarmBackup.ps1" \\SomeServer\Backups Full 0 D:\Logs\Backups 0 "D:\Documents\PowerShell Scripts","D:\SomeFolder"*

**Result: (From Log File)**

```
  Additional Directories to be included:
     D:\Documents\PowerShell Scripts,D:\SomeFolder
```

---

I've tried a couple of different methods for those parameters but I can't seem to get them to be seen as 2 separate strings in the string array. I'm hardcoding them for now, but it seems like there must be a way to make this work since it's totally valid when run from the shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the -Command switch instead of the -File switch, and then use the invocation operator '&'. Here is a link to an example of doing this with scheduled tasks:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/12/schedule-powershell-scripts-that-require-input-values.aspx

Something like:

```
-Command "& 'D:\Documents\PowerShell Scripts\FarmBackup.ps1' '\\SomeServer\Backups' 'Full' 0 'D:\Logs\Backups' 0 'D:\Documents\PowerShell Scripts','D:\SomeFolder'"
```

I tested this solution by creating a script with the contents:

```
param([string[]] $x)
Write-Host $x.Count
```

Then called it in the following two ways:

```
powershell -File ".\TestScript.ps1" "what1,what2"
```

with result : 1

and

```
powershell -Command "& .\TestScript.ps1 what1,what2"
```

with result: 2

Answer (score 2):

Another option, when the options get too complex and you're tired of fiddling with quotes, backticks, etc is to use the underused -EncodedCommand parameter on PowerShell.exe e.g.:

```
C:\PS> $cmd = "c:\temp\foo.ps1 'D:\Documents\PowerShell Scripts','D:\SomeFolder'"
C:\PS> $cmd
c:\temp\foo.ps1 'D:\Documents\PowerShell Scripts','D:\SomeFolder'
C:\PS> $bytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($cmd)
C:\PS> $encodedCmd = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
C:\PS> $encodedCmd
YwA6AFwAdABlAG0AcABcAGYAbwBvAC4AcABzADEAIAAnAEQAOgBcAEQAbwBjAHUAbQBlAG4AdABzAFwAUABvAHcAZQByAFMAaABlAGwAbAAgAFMAYwByAGkAcAB0AHMAJwAsACcARAA6AFwAUwBvAG0AZQBGAG8AbABkAGUAcgAnAA==
C:\PS> powershell.exe -encodedCommand YwA6AFwAdABlAG0AcABcAGYAbwBvAC4AcABzADEAIAAnAEQAOgBcAEQAbwBjAHUAbQBlAG4AdABzAFwAUABvAHcAZQByAFMAaABlAGwAbAAgAFMAYwByAGkAcAB0AHMAJwAsACcARAA6AFwAUwBvAG0AZQBGAG8AbABkAGUAcgAnAA==
param1[0] is D:\Documents\PowerShell Scripts
param1[1] is D:\SomeFolder
```

Admittedly, not something that would be exactly readable/understandable by someone else. :-) You'd have to doc the command in the description of the scheduled task.

Comment: This is an extremely interesting solution. However, it's important that the parameters are clearly understandable for others who have to maintain the scheduled task. However, I will definitely remember this technique in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, understandable it definitely is *not* but occasionally "understandable" starts to look less appealing after you've banged your head too long trying to get the parameters to work.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using PowerShell for SharePoint and have created several Scheduled Task to trigger them at various intervals.

This is how i do it and it worked for me all the time.

Syntax : *[Path to ur script'] -Param1Name 'Value1' -Param2Name 'Value2' -Param3Name 'Value3'*

Here is a real example :

**D:\Scripts\Global.ps1 -DataLocation 'D:\Scripts' -DeploymentParameters 'Deploymentparameters' -Deployments 'Deployments' -GlobalParameters 'GlobalParameters' -SiteUrl 'https://my.sp.company.com'**