# Passing parameters to powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, parameters, cmd

I'm trying to run a powershell script from the run dialog (will be used as a scheduled task), and I'm having troubles passing parameters.

The script will take in two parameters, named title and msg.
The script is located in: `D:\Tasks Scripts\Powershell\script.ps1`

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
powershell.exe -noexit 'D:\Tasks Scripts\Powershell\script.ps1' -title 'Hello world' -msg 'This is a test message'
```

But it fails upon reading the parameters.

Running `.\script.ps1 -title 'Hello world' -msg 'This is a test message'` on powershell works fine.

Comment: Use -command Check this SO answer -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691781/scheduled-task-for-powershell-script-with-string-array-parameter

Comment: It would help if you'd tell us what "it fails" means.  Quote the error message if there is one, or tell us what happens and what you expected to happen instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-file` before the path to your script:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -file 'D:\Tasks Scripts\Powershell\script.ps1' etc...
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually run powershell scripts from cmd.exe because this is portable
(works out-of-the-box on others' computers, like developer folks or clients):
no need to worry about Set-ExecutionPolicy or associating the .ps1 extension.

I create the file with .cmd extension (instead of .ps1), and copy&paste a short,
constant code to the first line(s) that invokes powershell.exe and passes the rest
of the file to it.
Passing arguments is tricky. I have multiple variants of the constant code
because the general case is painful.

1. when not passing arguments, the .cmd file looks like this:

   ```
   @powershell -c ".(iex('{#'+(gc '%~f0' -raw)+'}'))" & goto :eof
   # ...arbitrary PS code here...
   write-host hello, world!
   ```

   This uses the -Command argument of powershell.exe. Powershell reads the .cmd
   file as text, puts it in a ScriptBlock with the first line commented out,
   and evaluates it with the '.' command.
   Further [command line arguments](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx)
   can be added to the Powershell invocation as required (e.g. -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted,
   -Sta etc.)
2. when passing arguments that do not contain spaces or are 'single-quoted'
   (which is non-standard in cmd.exe), the one-liner is this:

   ```
   @powershell -c ".(iex('{#'+(gc($argv0='%~f0') -raw)+'}'))" %* & goto :eof

   write-host this is $argv0 arguments: "[$($args -join '] [')]"
   ```

   `param()` declarations could be used as well, `$args` is not obligatory.
   `$argv0` is used to compensate for the missing `$MyInvocation.PS*` info.
   Examples:

   ```
   G:\>lala.cmd
   this is G:\lala.cmd arguments: []

   G:\>lala.cmd "1 2" "3 4"
   this is G:\lala.cmd arguments: [1] [2] [3] [4]

   G:\>lala.cmd '1 2' '3 4'
   this is G:\lala.cmd arguments: [1 2] [3 4]
   ```
3. when passing arguments that are "double-quoted" but do not contain
   the & and ' characters, I use a two-liner to replace all " with '

   ```
   @echo off& set A= %*& set B=@powershell -c "$argv0='%~f0';.(iex('{'
   %B%+(gc $argv0|select -skip 2|out-string)+'}'))" %A:"='%&goto :eof

   write-host this is $argv0 arguments: "[$($args -join '] [')]"
   ```

   (Note that the space is important in the `A= %*` assignment for the
   argument-less case.)
   Results:

   ```
   G:\>lala.cmd
   this is G:\lala.cmd arguments: []

   G:\>lala.cmd "1 2" "3 4"
   this is G:\lala.cmd arguments: [1 2] [3 4]

   G:\>lala.cmd '1 2' '3 4'
   this is G:\lala.cmd arguments: [1 2] [3 4]
   ```
4. the most general case passes the arguments via environment variables
   thus Powershell's `param()` declaration does not work. In this case the
   arguments are expected to be "double-quoted" and may contain ' or &
   (except for the path of the .cmd file itself):

   ```
   ;@echo off & setlocal & set A=1& set ARGV0=%~f0
   ;:loop
   ;set /A A+=1& set ARG%A%=%1& shift& if defined ARG%A% goto :loop
   ;powershell -c ".(iex('{',(gc '%ARGV0%'|?{$_ -notlike ';*'}),'}'|out-string))"
   ;endlocal & goto :eof
   for ($i,$arg=1,@(); test-path -li "env:ARG$i"; $i+=1) { $arg += iex("(`${env:ARG$i}).Trim('`"')") }
   write-host this is $env:argv0 arguments: "[$($arg -join '] [')]"
   write-host arg[5] is ($arg[5]|%{if($_){$_}else{'$null'}})
   ```

   (Note that in the first line `A=1&` must not contain space.)
   Result:

   ```
   G:\>lala.cmd "a b" "c d" "e&f" 'g' "h^j"
   this is G:\lala.cmd arguments: [a b] [c d] [e&f] ['g'] [h^j]
   arg[5] is $null
   ```